# Automatically modify a form and submit it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**What I trying to do:**
Display a number of products that are defined by product id(s) and when the user chooses a certain product, I'll open a different webpage that automatically fills in some forms with those details and click the submit button (basically add that specific item to cart)

**My main question is:**
Is there anyway that I can do this besides using javascript?
Is it possible to do something like this on rails/ pure ruby (would really like to see if there is a solution for this in ruby)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need Javascript.

The reason here is because as long as your app has to respond to some user interaction, say choosing a certain product, the server has no way of knowing that an event has happened unless its is explicitly told.

Comment: You can still let Rails do the javascript for you with some remote calls.

Comment: True, but either way, you probably have to code some JS yourself.

Comment: are there any alternatives to javascript? and what do you guys mean by let rails do the javascript?

Comment: No. As long as you're doing web development, you'll have to use JS either way.

Comment: I've never done javascript before so I'm gonna ask this probably dumb question. Can I put javascript on my own page that would -- open a different page and automatically fill + submit a form on a different website? (I don't have control on the "different website")

Comment: You can use JS to open another page, but no, you cannot control the different website. Even if you could, that would lead to all sorts of security nastiness.